# Unable to pass datas for HighCharts Maps javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, highcharts

I am new to `reactJS`. I am using `HighCharts Maps Api` for loading Map Charts

Here's the Sample Code I wrote,

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import mapDataWorld from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json';
import mapDataIndia from '@highcharts/map-collection/countries/in/in-all.geo.json';
import mapDataAustralia from '@highcharts/map-collection/countries/au/au-all.geo.json';
import mapDataUSA from '@highcharts/map-collection/countries/us/us-all.geo.json';
import { Button } from 'antd';
require('highcharts/modules/map')(Highcharts);
class MapChartWidget extends React.Component {
    state={
        backWorldButtonDisable:true,
        options : {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            colorAxis: {
                min: 0,
                stops: [[0.4, '#ffff00'], [0.65, '#bfff00'], [1, '  #40ff00']]
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: (e)=>{this.mapDataChange(e)}
                        }
                    }
                },
                mapline: {
                    showInLegend: false,
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                  mapData:mapDataWorld,
                  data: [['in',5],['au',10],['us',97]],
                  states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: '#BADA55'
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                  }
                }
            ],

        },
    }
    mapDataChange(value){
        if(value.point.name === "India"){
            this.setState({
                backWorldButtonDisable:false,
                options : {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    colorAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        stops: [[0.4, '#ffff00'], [0.65, '#bfff00'], [1, '  #40ff00']]
                    },
                    series: [
                        {
                          mapData:mapDataIndia,
                          data: [['in',5],['au',10],['us',97]],
                          states: {
                            hover: {
                                color: '#BADA55'
                            }
                        },
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.name}'
                          }
                        }
                    ],

                },
            })
        }

    }


    render() {   
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <Button onClick={this.onBacktoMapClick.bind(this)}  size="small">Back to World Map</Button>
            <HighchartsReact  callback={this.props.chartRefCallback} containerProps={{ style: { width: '100%', height: 'calc(100% - 50px)' } }} options={this.state.options} constructorType={'mapChart'} highcharts={Highcharts} />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(MapChartWidget);
```

Output Image:
The World Map gets Loaded. 
[image]

On Double Clicking India, India Map gets Loaded. (I don't know why it can't get loaded in Single Click)
[image]

On `India` Map, I will be passing values for Data like this `data: [ ['in-py', 3],['in-ld', 2]]`. But When I pass these values in the Code, India Map is not Loading.

Error I Got:
[image]
After Clicking India, It loads the world map with no data
[image]
But when I pass these values `data: [['in',5],['au',10],['us',97]]` inside the data parameter in `mapDataChange` function, India Map gets Loaded as the first set of Output Images. Since the values are for country Map, it can't be showed in India Map.

In the above code, Options has the parameter for the Map Chart. In Initial, I load the World Map with Data. Later when user clicked on India, `mapDataChange` will be called, In this function, I am resetting the Options in reactJS State for India Map with values to be loaded. In this function, If I pass values for Data like this `data: [ ['in-py', 3],['in-ld', 2]]`, after refresh my page, On clicking India in the World Map,India Map is not Loading, World Map is still there. If I pass these values `data: [['in',5],['au',10],['us',97]]`, after refresh my page, On clicking India in the World Map, India Map gets Loaded. Since the values are for country Map, it can't be showed in India Map. I don't know how to fix this problem.
Please help me to fix this problem. I want these values `data: [ ['in-py', 3],['in-ld', 2]]` to be shown on India Map

Answer (score 0):

The map should be defined in the chart config, not in the series object. Otherwise, chart updating is disturbed.

```
chart: {
   map: mapDataWorld
}
```

Please check the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/drilldown-enepas?file=index.js